# Issues deploying node / react / redux app to heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku, webpack, babeljs

So I'm having some issues with pushing my app to heroku. Locally it runs and builds fine but it crashes when I try to deploy on heroku. Here's the log I'm seeing after deploying to heroku:

```
2017-05-18T16:56:47.252771+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the pluralsight-redux-starter package,
2017-05-18T16:56:47.252849+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2017-05-18T16:56:47.252939+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2017-05-18T16:56:47.253015+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm run build:html
2017-05-18T16:56:47.253089+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
2017-05-18T16:56:47.253159+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs pluralsight-redux-starter
2017-05-18T16:56:47.253227+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
2017-05-18T16:56:47.253304+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls pluralsight-redux-starter
2017-05-18T16:56:47.253382+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2017-05-18T16:56:47.256870+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-05-18T16:56:47.257025+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2017-05-18T16:56:47.257079+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2017-05-18T16:56:47.345310+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-05-18T16:56:47.336090+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-05-18T16:55:58.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2017-05-18T16:59:46.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user dgravelle54@gmail.com
2017-05-18T17:00:08.286603+00:00 app[api]: Release v4 created by user dgravelle54@gmail.com
2017-05-18T17:00:08.286603+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 8f4c395a by user dgravelle54@gmail.com
2017-05-18T17:00:08.618011+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-05-18T16:59:46.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2017-05-18T17:00:11.772019+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm run build`
2017-05-18T17:00:14.380808+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-05-18T17:00:14.380822+00:00 app[web.1]: > pluralsight-redux-starter@1.0.0 prebuild /app
2017-05-18T17:00:14.380823+00:00 app[web.1]: > npm run build:html
2017-05-18T17:00:14.380823+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-05-18T17:00:15.182395+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-05-18T17:00:15.182406+00:00 app[web.1]: > pluralsight-redux-starter@1.0.0 build:html /app
2017-05-18T17:00:15.182407+00:00 app[web.1]: > babel-node tools/buildHtml.js
2017-05-18T17:00:15.182408+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-05-18T17:00:16.180115+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/logger.js:41
2017-05-18T17:00:16.180126+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw new Constructor(this._buildMessage(msg));
2017-05-18T17:00:16.180127+00:00 app[web.1]:     ^
2017-05-18T17:00:16.180128+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-05-18T17:00:16.180129+00:00 app[web.1]: ReferenceError: [BABEL] /app/tools/buildHtml.js: Unknown option: base.Children. Check out http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/options/ for more information about options.
2017-05-18T17:00:16.180131+00:00 app[web.1]: A common cause of this error is the presence of a configuration options object without the corresponding preset name. Example:
2017-05-18T17:00:16.180131+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-05-18T17:00:16.180129+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-05-18T17:00:16.180132+00:00 app[web.1]: Invalid:
2017-05-18T17:00:16.180133+00:00 app[web.1]:   `{ presets: [{option: value}] }`
2017-05-18T17:00:16.180134+00:00 app[web.1]: Valid:
2017-05-18T17:00:16.180134+00:00 app[web.1]:   `{ presets: [['presetName', {option: value}]] }`
2017-05-18T17:00:16.180135+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-05-18T17:00:16.180137+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Logger.error (/app/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/logger.js:41:11)
2017-05-18T17:00:16.180136+00:00 app[web.1]: For more detailed information on preset configuration, please see http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/#pluginpresets-options.
2017-05-18T17:00:16.180137+00:00 app[web.1]:     at OptionManager.mergeOptions (/app/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:226:20)
2017-05-18T17:00:16.180138+00:00 app[web.1]:     at OptionManager.init (/app/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:368:12)
2017-05-18T17:00:16.180139+00:00 app[web.1]:     at File.initOptions (/app/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:212:65)
2017-05-18T17:00:16.180140+00:00 app[web.1]:     at new File (/app/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:135:24)
2017-05-18T17:00:16.180141+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Pipeline.transform (/app/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/pipeline.js:46:16)
2017-05-18T17:00:16.180142+00:00 app[web.1]:     at compile (/app/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:118:20)
2017-05-18T17:00:16.180142+00:00 app[web.1]:     at loader (/app/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:144:14)
2017-05-18T17:00:16.180143+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/app/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:154:7)
2017-05-18T17:00:16.180141+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.transformFileSync (/app/node_modules/babel-core/lib/api/node.js:152:10)
2017-05-18T17:00:16.204296+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "run" "build:html"
2017-05-18T17:00:16.204685+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
2017-05-18T17:00:16.204883+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2017-05-18T17:00:16.193941+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-05-18T17:00:16.205084+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! pluralsight-redux-starter@1.0.0 build:html: `babel-node tools/buildHtml.js`
2017-05-18T17:00:16.204007+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-112-generic
2017-05-18T17:00:16.204494+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v6.10.3
2017-05-18T17:00:16.205216+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2017-05-18T17:00:16.205385+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2017-05-18T17:00:16.205521+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the pluralsight-redux-starter@1.0.0 build:html script 'babel-node tools/buildHtml.js'.
2017-05-18T17:00:16.205654+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
2017-05-18T17:00:16.205790+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the pluralsight-redux-starter package,
2017-05-18T17:00:16.205926+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2017-05-18T17:00:16.206069+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2017-05-18T17:00:16.206205+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     babel-node tools/buildHtml.js
2017-05-18T17:00:16.206343+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
2017-05-18T17:00:16.206474+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs pluralsight-redux-starter
2017-05-18T17:00:16.206616+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
2017-05-18T17:00:16.206746+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls pluralsight-redux-starter
2017-05-18T17:00:16.206883+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2017-05-18T17:00:16.210443+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-05-18T17:00:16.210851+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2017-05-18T17:00:16.210971+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2017-05-18T17:00:16.222137+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-05-18T17:00:16.229747+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-112-generic
2017-05-18T17:00:16.230016+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "run" "build"
2017-05-18T17:00:16.230230+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v6.10.3
2017-05-18T17:00:16.230422+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
2017-05-18T17:00:16.230611+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2017-05-18T17:00:16.230764+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! pluralsight-redux-starter@1.0.0 prebuild: `npm run build:html`
2017-05-18T17:00:16.230889+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2017-05-18T17:00:16.231035+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2017-05-18T17:00:16.231171+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the pluralsight-redux-starter@1.0.0 prebuild script 'npm run build:html'.
2017-05-18T17:00:16.231297+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
2017-05-18T17:00:16.231428+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the pluralsight-redux-starter package,
2017-05-18T17:00:16.231554+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2017-05-18T17:00:16.231697+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2017-05-18T17:00:16.231827+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm run build:html
2017-05-18T17:00:16.231955+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
2017-05-18T17:00:16.232183+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs pluralsight-redux-starter
2017-05-18T17:00:16.232315+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
2017-05-18T17:00:16.232440+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls pluralsight-redux-starter
2017-05-18T17:00:16.232578+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2017-05-18T17:00:16.236064+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-05-18T17:00:16.236264+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2017-05-18T17:00:16.236373+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2017-05-18T17:00:16.327400+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-05-18T17:00:16.337382+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Here's a link to my current repo.

https://github.com/dgravelle/magic-redux

I've gone through a bunch of iterations now trying to get this working on heroku but I've had no success. If anyone could shed some light on the issue here I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

on Heroku, you are not a root administrator, it means that you don't have the write permission.

if you want to run your server on heroku, I think you can try to bundle your file in your local.

Comment: Oh I hadn't thought of doing that but that makes sense. I'll give that a shot. Thanks!